# Return and consume an iterator of mutable references from a closure

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

Are there any examples of functions that consume a closure that returns an `Iterator<Item = &mut T>`?

I've wanted to write a couple Rust functions that iterated over the contents of a collection several times, and possibly backwards.  `IntoIterator` alone does not suffice because it consumes its argument by value preventing multiple iterations.  Iterators can frequently cloned, but iterators of mutable references.

If we really only need iteration over the collections's exact elements, then we might use that `&mut C: IntoIterator` for all Rust collection types `C`.  Accepting [RFC 2289](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2289) syntax, this could look like:

```
fn batch_normalization<II: ?Sized>(v: &mut II)
where
    for<'a> &'a mut II: IntoIterator<Item = &'a mut Self, IntoIter: DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator>,
```

but the current form runs into a [compiler bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2289#issuecomment-409337644).  Also, this would not permit users to specify a "view" of the collection contents using iterator adapters, like `map`.

Intuitively, we should borrow the collection using a closure that rebuilds our iterator when called:

```
fn batch_normalization<F>(f: F)
where
    F: FnMut() -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut Self> + DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator
```

We cannot write that yet because (a) issues around `impl Trait` in traits have not yet been resolved, and (b) our `&mut Self` needs a lifetime, so we might write say:

```
fn batch_normalization<I, F: FnMut() -> I>(f: F)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = BorrowMut<Self>> + DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator
```

I've tried various formulations like this but none quite work, mostly because the `Item` outlives the iterator.

We should fix this the way `&'a mut C: IntoIterator<Item = &'a mut T>` does by explicitly tying the item's lifetime to the lifetime of `&mut self` in the `FnMut`.  In pseudocode:

```
fn batch_normalization<I, F: FnMut() -> I>(f: F)
where
    I: for<'a: F::Output> Iterator<Item = &'a mut Self> + DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator
```

How should one actually return an `Iterator<Item = &mut T>` from a closure passed as an argument?  Should one always use some `fn` pointer mess instead of a closure?  Roughly:

```
fn batch_normalization<'a, I, V: ?Sized>(v: &mut V, f: fn(&'a mut V) -> I)
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a mut Self> + DoubleEndedIterator + ExactSizeIterator 
{
   for x in f() { }
   // ...
   for x in f().rev() { } 
}
```

Comment: Iterators can usually be cloned cheaply. Would something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cefa555b7842c1f29d3d32bed63ed009&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) work for you? Besides: it would probably be useful if you could minimize your example a bit more. Like what is `Self` there? Is it important? As a reminder: [MCVE].

Comment: I don't understand *this would not permit users to specify a "view" of the collection contents using iterator adapters, like map*. You can't iterate twice over the same `Map` anyway. It sounds like you might be looking for something more along the lines of a cursor-based API, not an iterator-based one.

Comment: Very good point about cloning iterators Lukas.  I'd think that adresses most such scenarios, thanks!  I'm afraid `std::slice::IterMut` cannot be cloned however: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.IterMut.html

Comment: Yes, a cursor-based API would definitely solve this @trentcl but cursors are slightly overkill, as I only need to restart the iterator several times, and it seems like it should be doable by using closures and iterators together.  In fact, there is one interesting advantage to cursors in that a user cannot provide a closure that returns different things on different runs.

Comment: I meant "view" in the database sense, so I have a `HashMap<X,(Y,Z)>` but maybe I want to filter it based on `X` and only give the function an `Iterator<Item=&mut Z>`.  This would not be compatible with the `&mut C: IntoIterator` trick, which is maybe a distraction.

Comment: I have clarified the question as being about returning an `Iterator<Item=&mut T>` from a closure, which is what I meant by "view".

Comment: *Iterators can frequently cloned, but iterators of mutable references.* — you lost words.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do precisely this with closures because the `Fn*` traits do not support binding a return type to the lifetime of their `self` argument.  Right now, the `Fn*` traits read

```
pub trait FnOnce<Args> {
    type Output;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
pub trait FnMut<Args>: FnOnce<Args> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
pub trait Fn<Args>: FnMut<Args> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

but this would require these traits read like

```
pub trait FnOnce<Args> {
    type Output<'fn>;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output<'static>;
}
pub trait FnMut<Args>: FnOnce<Args> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut<'fn>(&'fn mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output<'fn>;
}
pub trait Fn<Args>: FnMut<Args> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call<'fn>(&'fn self, args: Args) -> Self::Output<'fn>;
}
```

These are unstable interfaces so they could perhaps eventually be changes through the RFC process, maybe with some special `'fn` liftime syntax like `FnMut() -> impl Iterator<Item = &'fn mut Self>`, or maybe even with a parametrized the type parameter `Args` as `Args<'fn>`.  Rust internals is the proper forum for this question.